# Find <a> with image extension in href (jQuery)

Tags: jquery, image, find, href

I need to find (and hide) all links with images (.jpg, .png, .gif) in href as they're causing my wordpress excerpts to break.

Many thanks.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

```
$('a').filter(function() {
    return $(this).attr('href').match(/\.(jpg|png|gif)/i);
}).hide();
```

Comment: It also would work in some edge cases like image1.jpg&uname=tom ... however in saying that it would also match the extension if it occurred as part of the URL elsewhere... but that seems unlikely.

Answer (score 3):

Okay, figured it :P

```
$("a[href$='.jpg']").addClass('hide');
```

Comment: You could instead call `.hide()` if you'd rather.

Comment: You should consider for .jpg , .jpeg , .JPG and .JPEG
Having David example to be case insensitive, and adding jpeg, should to the trick. (I'm not good with regex to write a proper answer, sorry)