# How to find links with a specific extension using jQuery

Tags: jquery, hyperlink, traversal

I am trying to traverse and find links with a specific extension (*.ashx) so that I can open the link in a new tab. (Sitefinity does not allow target="_blank").

I can find the  tags using jQuery, but I need to then filter it more so that when I click on an  tag with an extension of .ashx, I can open this in a new window.

Something like this

```
<a href="anniversary.sflb.ashx"> Anniversary </a>
```

Many thanks,
James

Comment: possible duplicate of [Find <a> with image extension in href (jQuery)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1826278/find-a-with-image-extension-in-href-jquery)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It would be better to use the attribute contains selector

```
$("a[href*='.ashx']").each(
  function() {
  //Do stuff
});
```

see [http://jsfiddle.net/graham/Fa6kV/](http://jsfiddle.net/graham/Fa6kV/2/)

Comment: Thanks guys, these all seem like options I can try and see which works the best for me.

Answer (score 2):

The two answers provided so far (graham's and Steve's) are both potentially inaccurate: graham's will sometimes match links that have `ashx` somewhere in the string, but not necessarily at the end of the string -- `bashxml.php` would match, for instance.  Steve's, meanwhile, will not match if there's a query string, as he notes.

You can get round this by doing the filtering yourself:

```
$('a').each(function() {
    if (this.pathname.substr(-5) === '.ashx') { // if the last 5 characters of the pathname are .ashx
        // do your processing here
    }
});
```

See [documentation on the Location object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.location#Location_object).

Comment: good point, but it would work with a dot included - $("a[href*='.ashx']")

Comment: @graham Yes, that would help. Mine's still *more* reliable, though! :-)

Answer (score 0):

You could use the [attribute ends with selector](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-ends-with-selector/):

```
$("a[href$='.ashx']")
```

Note: this wouldn't work if your links have a query string or some other suffix in the `href` attribute