# JQquery selector for a file link

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I need to write a selector in jQuery for finding all links to various media file. So far, I was able to find only selectors to specific files, for example, `$('a[href$=".pdf"]')`.

I need to locate only links that will to any media file, such as, pdf, doc, jpg, etc.
For example, this link should not be matched by the required selector 
`<a href="../pdfs/christmas/">` as it is just just a web address and not a resource. I am looking for a universal solution that would work without predefined set of file extensions that we need to match.

Is it possible? Thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Find <a> with image extension in href (jQuery)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1826278/find-a-with-image-extension-in-href-jquery) Example: https://codepen.io/paulodiogo/pen/eeyxKz

Comment: this code matches <a href="../pdfs/christmas/" /> as a link to a file, which is wrong.